# Entity Framework and NHibernate - Is caching still a service layer responsibility?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, caching, orm

Prior to using ORMs we always performed object caching in our service layer. This gave us the ability to switch between different data layers without having to change our caching implementation.

Nowadays we use both Entity Framework (mainly code first) and NHibernate. NHibernate seems to have much better caching features with several 2nd level cache providers available.

Another problem I am faced with is that for both of the above ORMs we make use of lazy loaded properties. So if we are retrieving an object from the cache we normally have to reattach it to the current ObjectContext/ISession, something we can't really do in our service layer.

So should I really be looking at implementing caching at the repository/data layer; and is it likely that I will find a common solution that will work for EF and NH?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [CQRS pattern](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/)? Because [caching is policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/02/588350.aspx), I'm suspicious of trying to automate these decisions with a "one size fits all" cache like a second layer cache. E.g., if what you really want to cache is the HTML for your site home page, then a second layer cache is just a waste of memory and an invitation to bugs.

CQRS turns these mechanical considerations into policy decisions. And it's ORM-agnostic.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for the links. Udi's video really helped me get to grips with this (http://bit.ly/d29jZU). In your experience, does CQRS work well for web/ecommerce applications, especially where you have views that will likely contain a mixture of "stale" (product information), personalized (cart, profile) and live (well as live as possible e.g. stock levels) data. Udi also talks of handing off a command and issuing an asynchronous response if there's a problem - something that's not typically easy to implement in web applications.

Comment: Well, amazon.com pioneered this stuff ("eventually consistent"), so yes, I'd say it's worked out OK for e-commerce. Obviously, you have to choose what can be stale and what can't. But the point is that's a business, rather than tech consideration.

Comment: Is it something that could be added to an existing application or should we really be making such architectural decisions well before we start writing any code? Obviously features like http caching could be added at any time without major implications.

Comment: No major implications other than a broken site due to incorrect cache expiration policies, anyway. While it's *best* to architect this in from the outset, you *can* add caching in piece by piece if you're careful. Profile, find a performance hotspot, design the correct cache policy, and add it in *just that place.* Test like crazy, and grow from there. Unlike a second layer cache, you can easily do this at one place at a time, and thus limit the QA scope.

Comment: The more I look into CQRS the more convincing it looks. Thanks for opening my eyes to this. Now, off to learn more :)

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that 2nd level cache provided by the ORM will cache the data based on the actual resultset retrieved from the database. This can give you a lot of overhead because the object instantiation and data population is pretty costly.

The advantage is that lazy loading etc will work fine, but big results will still use up a lot of resources when repopulating the objects.

We use a combination of 2nd level cache and the ASP.NET cache in our webapplication because of the costly overhead, which in rare cases saves us as much as several seconds (!), but with the drawback of not being able to lazy load collections or update the entities.

This is based on NHibernate only, I have never worked with entity framework but I'm guessing all ORM frameworks suffer from this.